# Going through all folders in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

I want to go through all folders inside a directory:

```
directory\  
   folderA\
         a.cpp
   folderB\
         b.cpp
   folderC\
         c.cpp
   folderD\
         d.cpp
```

The name of the folders are all known.
Specifically, I am trying to count the number of lines of code on each of the `a.cpp`, `b.cpp`, `c.pp` and `d.cpp` source files. So, go inside `folderA` and read `a.cpp`, count lines and then go back to directory, go inside `folderB`, read `b.cpp`, count lines etc.

This is what I have up until now,

```
dir = directory_path
for folder_name in folder_list():
    dir = os.path.join(dir, folder_name)
    with open(dir) as file:
        source= file.read()
    c = source.count_lines()
```

but I am new to Python and have no idea if my approach is appropriate and how to proceed. Any example code shown will be appreciated!

Also, does the `with open` handles the file opening/closing as it should for all those reads or more handling is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
import glob
import os

path = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/'  # give the path where all the folders are located
list_of_folders = ['test1', 'test2']  # give the program a list with all the folders you need
names = {}  # initialize a dict

for each_folder in list_of_folders:  # go through each file from a folder
    full_path = os.path.join(path, each_folder)  # join the path
    os.chdir(full_path)  # change directory to the desired path

    for each_file in glob.glob('*.cpp'):  # self-explanatory
        with open(each_file) as f:  # opens a file - no need to close it
            names[each_file] = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip())

    print(names)
```

**Output:**

```
{'file1.cpp': 2, 'file3.cpp': 2, 'file2.cpp': 2}
{'file1.cpp': 2, 'file3.cpp': 2, 'file2.cpp': 2}
```

Regarding the `with` question, you don't need to close the file or make any other checks. You should be safe as it is now.

**You may**, however, check if the `full_path` exists as somebody (you) could mistakenly delete a folder from your PC (a folder from `list_of_folders`)

You can do this by `os.path.isdir` which returns `True` if the file exists:

`os.path.isdir(full_path)`

PS: I used Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python 3's `os.walk()` to traverse all subdirectories and files of a given path, opening each file and do your logic. You can use a 'for' loop to walk it, simplifying your code greatly.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Answer (score 0):

As manglano said, os.walk()

you can generate a list of folder.

```
[src for src,_,_ in os.walk(sourcedir)]
```

you can generate a list of file path.

```
[src+'/'+file for src,dir,files in os.walk(sourcedir) for file in files]
```