# Preffered way of counting lines, characters and words from a file as a whole in Python

Tags: python

I have found 2 ways of **counting the lines of a file** as they can be seen below. (note: I need to read the file as a whole and not line-by-line)

Trying to get a feel of which approach is better in terms of efficiency and/or good-coding-style.

```
names = {} 
for each_file in glob.glob('*.cpp'):
    with open(each_file) as f:
        names[each_file] = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip())
```

(as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36411684/6003691))

```
data = open('test.cpp', 'r').read()
print(len(data.splitlines()), len(data.split()), len(data))
```

(as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23094063/3286832))

And in the same topic, regarding the **counting the number of characters** and the **counting number of words** in a file; is there a better way than the one suggested above?

Comment: the most efficient way is probably this one, but you say you cannot read the file line by line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416522/counting-characters-and-lines-from-a-file-python-2-7?lq=1

Comment: I don't know about Python, but `wc -l` has always been good enough for me at a bash terminal :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generator expression for memory efficiency (this approach will avoid reading the whole file into memory). Here's a demonstration.

```
def count(filename, what):
    strategy = {'lines': lambda x: bool(x.strip()),
                'words': lambda x: len(x.split()),
                'chars': len
    }

    strat = strategy[what]
    with open(filename) as f:
        return sum(strat(line) for line in f)
```

input.txt:

```
this is
a test file
i just typed
```

output:

```
>>> count('input.txt', 'lines')
3
>>> count('input.txt', 'words')
8
>>> count('input.txt', 'chars')
33
```

Note that when counting characters, the newline characters are counted as well. Also note that this uses a pretty crude definition of "word" (you did not provide one), it just splits a line by whitespace and counts the elements of the returned list.

Comment: That is great! I am afraid I do not understand how these lamda statements work. If you have a link that explains it to a Python newbie that would be great cause from just googling it did not found any 'easy' examples.

Comment: @Karim The idea is to apply the pythonic version of the strategy pattern. We map strings to functions (the strategy) in a dictionary, and choose a strategy based on the second argument provided to the function. The values of the dictionary are regular functions. You could have defined these without the lambdas. For example, the second one is equivalent to `def wordcount(line): return len(line.split())`. If you want to learn more about the lambda, the first google hits are pretty decent.

Comment: @Karim also, the first one uses the "trick" that you can just add `True` and `False`, for example `True + False + True == 2`. `bool(string)` will  return `True` for any string that is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

Create a few test files and test them in a big loop to see the average times.
Make sure the test files fit your scenarios.

I used this code:

```
import glob
import time

times1 = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    names = {} 
    t0 = time.clock()
    with open("lines.txt") as f:
        names["lines.txt"] = sum(1 for line in f if line.strip())
        print names
    times1.append(time.clock()-t0)

times2 = []
for i in range(0,1000):
    names = {} 
    t0 = time.clock()
    data = open("lines.txt", 'r').read()
    print("lines.txt",len(data.splitlines()), len(data.split()), len(data))

    times2.append(time.clock()-t0)


print sum(times1)/len(times1)
print sum(times2)/len(times2)
```

and came out with the average timings:
0.0104755582104 and 
0.0180650466201 seconds

This was on a text file with 23000 lines. E.g:

```
print("lines.txt",len(data.splitlines()), len(data.split()), len(data))
```

outputs: ('lines.txt', 23056, 161392, 1095160)

Test this on your actual file set to get more accurate timing data.